# jquery filtered list select

Tags: jquery, filter

I have completed this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/) on 'Creating a “Filterable” Portfolio with jQuery' from nettuts+ and was wanting to tweek it a bit.

I would like to instead of clicking the top navigation and each category filters based on what was clicked, i want to click one 'Design' and if I click another 'CMS' they will show the items from both categories. When clicked again will turn that filter off and show whatever is selected.

so, in other words I want it to display what ever i select and I unselect by clicking the category again.

Below is the JS file I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {

            $('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maintaining an array of toggled elements. I can't test this, but its close I think.

**EDIT**: Now tested and working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('toggled_filter').parent().toggleClass('current'); // toggle a class for its state
        $(this).css('outline','none');

        var filterValList = [];
        $('.toggled_filter').each(function(){
          // add each text item to the list
          filterValList.push($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-'));
        });

        if($.inArray('all', filterValList) != -1 || filterValList.length === 0) {
          $('ul#filter li:first').addClass('current');
              $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
              $('ul#filter li:first').removeClass('current');
              $('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
                 var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
                 // go through each of the classes on each element 
                 // and hide them if they aren't toggled on
                 var match_found = false;
                 for(var i in classes){  
                   if($.inArray(classes[i], filterValList) != -1) {
                     match_found = true;
                   }
                 }
                 // check and see if anything matched
                 if(!match_found){
                   $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                 } else {
                   $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                 }

              });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried the above script, but seems to be doing the same thing as the  first.

Comment: I was able to get the source of the demo and try this out and fix the problems. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Tried out the new script but only lets me select one category at a time.

Comment: Here is the code running on jsbin. It works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/izeki  - (images not loaded on purpose.)

Comment: I just tested that link in IE6-8 - FF3.5 and Safari and it works in all of them. Are you having cache issues?

Comment: Ok, got the your script working perfectly. Turns out I was calling another similar script instead of the right one. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.